# Angular 1.7 Filtering Table based off select box

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/13415/

I have an object called 'orders' that contains a list of foods, filterable by type with the select box below. The select box contains the filter for the food category of the orders. I want to be able to filter out a table using angular using this select box.

```
$scope.orders = { 
              "order1": {food_name: "apple", type: 1},
              "order2": {food_name: "banana", type: 1},
              "order3": {food_name: "carrot", type: 2},
              "order4": {food_name: "cereal", type: 3},
              "order5": {food_name: "wheat", type: 3}
              }

$scope.foodCategories = [{id:0,name:"All"}, {id:1,name:"Fruit"},{id:2,name:"Vegatable"}, {id:3,name:"Grains"}];
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app = "myApp" ng-controller="foodCntrl">
 Select Food Type:
 <select 
        class="form-control" ng-model="foodCategories" ng-options="type as type.name for type in foodCategories">
 </select>

  <table class="table">
       <thead>
        <tr>
         <th>Food Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="f in orders | filter:foodCategories.id">
             <td>{{f.food_name}}</td>
       </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

 </div>
```

I am getting the angular console error: 
**Error: filter:notarray
Not an array** when using filter:foodCategories on the table ng-repeat.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `orders` isn't an array, it is an object.  you can't filter objects.

Comment: Fixed http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/13417/

Comment: I retagged - it's not Angular - that's for Angular 2+ - Use AngularJS

Answer (score 0):

Just add a filter for the property "type" in your orders array, and for the "foodCategories" make the id for the "All" category empty string as so {id:"",name:"All"}.

```
  <table class="table">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Food Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="f in orders | filter:{type: doorTypeSelect.id}">
         <td>{{f.food_name}}</td>
   </tr>
```

Here is a working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/4V0i1AIGRovnOUSp7eom?p=preview